# CSVHelper - Issue with Date and decimal value(seperator used as Comma instead of Dot) on export to CSV

Tags: c#

I have a requirement to convert the inputfile xml to CSV, for this I have used CSV Helper.

After converting xml to object and then to csv, there are two columns in CSV file which are not returning the result as expected.

1. DateColumn
2. Amount Column

Date Column value in object from CSVWriter - "2019-01-25"
value in csv is 01/25/2019

Amount column in object from CSVWRITER - 0,95
value in CSV is 0,95

```
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(filename))

            using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter))
            {
                streamWriter.WriteLine("sep=;");
                csvWriter.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;

                csvWriter.Configuration.AutoMap<class>();
                csvWriter.WriteHeader<Camt054>();
                csvWriter.NextRecord();
                csvWriter.WriteRecords(new[] {singleclassobject});


                streamWriter.Flush();
            }
```

Expected Value in CSV 
Date -  2019-01-25
Amount - 9.98

Actual Value in CSV
Date - 01/25/2019
Amount - 9,98

Answer (score 1):

Try to set culture when write objects

```
csvWriter.Configuration.CultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
```

Comment: beware, if the machine running your code has en-US locale but formats are customized, you'll get customized CSV format !

Answer (score 0):

You can set the configuration's CultureInfo value to specify a specific format. Both the US culture and the Invariant culture use the dot as the decimal separator. No culture uses the ISO8601 date format though.

You can set the CultureInfo with :

```
csvWriter.Configuration.CultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

You can specify the date format in two ways:

- You can specify the format for every DateTime value or
- Specify the format for specific columns only

For the entire file with :

```
var configuration=csvWriter.Configuration;
configuration.TypeConverterOptionsCache.GetOptions<DateTime>().Formats = new []{"yyyy-MM-dd"};
```

Or for a specific column in the mapping class with :

```
var memberMap = Map(m => m.Date);
memberMap.TypeConverterOption.Format("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

The actual syntax may be different from one version to another as CsvHelper's API changes quite frequently. For example, older SO questions used :

```
Map(m => m.Date).TypeConverterOption("yyy-MM-dd");
```

to set the the date format

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I got the exepected values..I didnt make any code changes, its related to Region settings in Control Panel, the decimal seperator was "," in Control Panel and date also, once I changed, the results were as expected.

Comment: @harish that's the bug, not the solution - you can't force every user of your application to change their locale for you. You can't expect to get CSVs *only* in the machine'slocale, especially in web applications.  String formatting uses the regional settings unless you explicitly specify the culture. In fact, C# analyzers generate localization warnings each time you use `ToString()` or `Parse()` without specifying a culture.

Comment: Panagiotis - now after I use the suggestion given by you for decimal seprator its working as expected, displaying dot instead comma in excel.. but Date is not working yet it still shows 25/01/2019 in excel after using the mapper class  Map(m => m.BookingDate).Index(0).TypeConverterOption.Format("yyyy-MM-dd"); and registering it in csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CamtModelMapper>();

Comment: Date still I get in excel 25/01/2019 instead 2019-01-25. classMapCode Map(m => m.BookingDate).Name("Booking Date").Index(0).TypeConverterOption
                .Format("yyyy-MM-dd");

Comment: @harish Excel isn't a text editor. What does the *CSV file* look like? Excel understands dates and displays them formatted according to the user's (your) locale. You can change the cell's style to change how a date appears but that won't change the actual value.

Comment: Date from .NET object is 2019-01-25 but in csv file the value is 25/01/2019, my locale in control panel for date is set to dd/MM/yyyy(french format)..

Comment: Date from .NET object is 2019-01-25 but in csv file the value is 25/01/2019, my locale in control panel for date is set to dd/MM/yyyy(french format)..yes I can change the cell style and it displays the value as expected without modifying the value, but when the user opens the Excel file, by default the date value should be be in format yyyy-MM-dd...